# How to avoid duplicate results when import from RSS

Tags: php, mysql, rss

I'm importing data from RSS to mysql using core php, every x hours, but I'm struggling with duplicate entries.

```
$rss_url = 'https://promograd.bg/feed/agg/common.xml?a=143';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
    foreach($xml->ITEM as $item) {
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->TITLE);
        $offerUrl = $item->URL;
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->DESCRIPTION);
        $offerTerms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->TERMS);
        $originalPrice = $item->ORIGINAL_PRICE;
        $finalPrice = $item->FINAL_PRICE;
        $offerDiscount = $item->DISCOUNT;
        $offerSales = $item->SALES;
        $offerEnds = $item->DEAL_END;
        $lat_coordinates = $item->LAT;
        $lng_coordinates = $item->LNG;
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->CITY);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->CATEGORY);

        $img = $item->IMAGE;

        $query = mysqli_query($link, "
        INSERT INTO......       
        }
```

My issue is when I run this script it will import the same results, with not much new.. How I can avoid duplicated results?

Comment: Use `insert ignore` on link as link will always be unique

Comment: Which node do you want to check for the duplicates?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar title for example

Comment: Don't check title for duplication. title can be same for multiple posts. but the link of post will always be unique

Comment: Where's the logic to check for duplicates? Do you use indices on your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you are checking the title for duplicate you can try this:-

```
$rss_url = 'https://promograd.bg/feed/agg/common.xml?a=143';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
$tempRecords = array(); // temp array store titles
foreach($xml->ITEM as $item) {
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->TITLE);
    if(in_array($title, $tempRecords)){ //skip if exists
        continue;
    }else{ // else insert
        //$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->TITLE);
        $tempRecords[] = $title; //assign to temp array

        $offerUrl = $item->URL;
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->DESCRIPTION);
        $offerTerms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->TERMS);
        $originalPrice = $item->ORIGINAL_PRICE;
        $finalPrice = $item->FINAL_PRICE;
        $offerDiscount = $item->DISCOUNT;
        $offerSales = $item->SALES;
        $offerEnds = $item->DEAL_END;
        $lat_coordinates = $item->LAT;
        $lng_coordinates = $item->LNG;
        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->CITY);
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $item->CATEGORY);

        $img = $item->IMAGE;

        $query = mysqli_query($link, "
        INSERT INTO......  
    }

    }
```

You can also do it using the mysql query, please refer the link

```
https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2016/03/22/mysql-insert-ignore-alternatives/
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique key on table for column which you do not want to duplicated.  Or you can put unique key on multiple columns like combination of title and url as well.

Now in inert query

use `insert ignore` to avoid insert duplicate entries

or use  `on duplicate key update` to update some fields when duplicate entry found. like if you want to update new price for same existing record.